# java.net.SocketException: Protocol not supported

Tags: java, sctp

I am trying to create a SCTP application.
I wrote a sample code to test if SCTP is supported on Ubuntu 14.04 with libsctp-dev installed.

```
    public class TestSctp {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            com.sun.nio.sctp.SctpChannel sc = com.sun.nio.sctp.SctpChannel.open();
            System.out.println("SCTP supported");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
java.net.SocketException: Protocol not supported
at sun.nio.ch.sctp.SctpNet.socket0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.sctp.SctpNet.socket(SctpNet.java:85)
at sun.nio.ch.sctp.SctpChannelImpl.<init>(SctpChannelImpl.java:138)
at com.sun.nio.sctp.SctpChannel.open(SctpChannel.java:166)
at TestSctp.main(TestSctp.java:7)
```

This is my java version:

`java version "1.8.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)`

I am unable to fix this exception.

Comment: Do you also have lksctp-tools installed?

Comment: So your test failed. Doesn't that suggest it isn't supoorted?

Comment: No, not necessarily. SCTP is supported by the linuxkernel. To use it in your application you have to add lksctp-tools not only libsctp-dev. @tej, to test if your system really supports sctp open a terminal and run `sctp_darn -H 0 -P 2500 -l`. From another terminal you can run a client with `sctp_darn -H 0 -P 2600 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 2500 -s` to verify SCTP is supported by your OS (Could be you have modified the kernel?).

Comment: @Frank The commands didnt work in my VM. I created a new ubuntu VM and it started working(even the sample java code). Guess my kernel was modified.